# Delphi 7 TComPort OnRxChar not fire

Tags: delphi, tcomport

I'm using `TComPort`
I use the `OnRxChar` event to control when byte are arrived.

I receive 3 bytes word for each command i send, but sometimes, `OnRxChar` receive only 2 bytes the remaining byte is not received, even if sent correctly 3 byte at time.

I think the remaining bytes is still in some buffers, but `OnRxChar` not fire for the last byte, why?

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT 1

Piece of code

```
procedure BraccioRobot.ComPort3RxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
  i:integer;
  BB : integer;
  Dist:double;
  Buff:array [0..10] of byte;
begin
FMsg:='Byte in:'+IntToStr(Count);
Synchronize(Log);
ComPort3.Read(Buff, Count);

for i:=0 to Count-1 do begin
  Rxbuff[CountRx+i]:=Buff[i];
end;
CountRx:=CountRx+Count;

if CountRx<3 then begin
  exit;
end;


// --------------------------
// 80 lines of code where I process the received data
```

EDIT 2
if after having received only 2 bytes, I send other 3 bytes, OnRxChar fire and i recive 4 bytes this time, the last of first word and the entire second word

like this:
    `A1 A2 | A3 B1 B2 B3`

EDIT 3

```
procedure BraccioRobot.Log;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(FMsg);
end;
```

I removed the call to Synchronize and now the event is called.
I need something to make the log when I do the tests.
How do?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `TComPort.OnRxChar` event is executed in the main thread. You are calling `Synchronize(Log)` in this event handler. This is bad. See [TThread.Synchronize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) where this is stated:`**Warning:** Do not call Synchronize from within the main thread. This can cause an infinite loop.` And this can also explain why you are missing an event call.

Comment: TComPort is executed in a **secondary thread of application**, the main thread manages only the window, and Synchronize is used for write Log on window

Comment: I think @LURD is on the right track. Default synchronization method is `smThreadSync` which means that TComThread.DispatchComMsg will call Synchronize(DoEvents). At least remove your Synchronize() call as a test.

Comment: Since we can't see your `Log` method, please remove that call and redo your test. Or strip down your code and provide a minimal executable example that exhibits your problem.

Comment: *I need something to make the log when I do the tests. How do?* Just call your Log() function without `Synchronize()`.

Comment: From the last update it looks as though it works, is that correct? Now, call the Log method without the Synchronize(). This is safe, since your event is executing in the main thread. You can test: `MainThreadID = GetCurrentThreadID`.

Comment: Ok, but **TComPort is executed in a secondary thread of application** is not secure update the main window from a secondary thread, How could I do?

Comment: It does not matter where the `TComPort` is executed. The event is called enclosed in a `Synchronize()` method, and thus executed in the main thread. Did you check my advice with the `MainThreadID = GetCurrentThreadID`?

Comment: Mex, as I wrote already, TComPort itself calls `Synchronize()` when it fires the `OnRxChar` event. The secondary thread of TComPort doesn't concern you.

Comment: @LU Please enter your thoughts as an answer, so we get the correct answer.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, done. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Ahhhhh, ok, I'm sorry,I'm sorry, I did not understand well.
Now it works fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, `TComPort.OnRxChar` event is executed in the main thread. You are calling `Synchronize(Log)` in this event handler. This is bad. See [TThread.Synchronize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) where this is stated:

> **Warning:** Do not call Synchronize from within the main thread. This can cause an infinite loop.

And this can also explain why you are missing an event call. The `TComPort.OnRxChar` event is already called with a `Synchronize()` statement, and adding another `Synchronize(Log)` call can cause messages from the system to get lost.

Just call `Log` without the `Synchronize` and it will work.